# conan.io package management - source only package

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, conan

this is not a request about header-only packages.  Those are straightforward

I've got a cross-platform library which I'd like to not package with any .a (or similar) prebuilt binaries but rather indicate its `.cpp` must be built along with the consuming application (`add_subdirectory` style).

The only way I see to do this are:

- `conan install -build` style
- Set up conan build profiles

Both of those two are reasonable, yet seem to be more effort than needed for a consumer who "just wants to recompile the C++" with whatever toolchain their top level CMake is pointed towards.

So, in other words, can conan serve similarly as a delivery mechanism for a git retrieve/`add_subdirectory` and present it as a CONAN_PKG?

Comment: You could just ``self.copy("*.cpp", ...)`` and copy files and headers in the final package, instead of binaries, and then get them into the consumer projects with ``imports()``. I think this is the same case as the one explained here (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/other_languages_package_manager/go.html) for golang

Comment: If that is not what you want, I think it might be better to file an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan, which is more friendly for discussion and 2 way feedback.

Comment: Fascinating idea.  Almost a "be careful what you wish for" category.  I figured my request was perhaps an established use case that I just wasn't familiar enough to know about.  If it turns out to be a feature request, I'll definitely head to the github link

Comment: I'm attaching to an existing highly similar conan issue https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7963 - however he has received no answer yet, unfortunately